# How to get range slider value in alert box using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap range slider where I define minimum and maximum value. Now, What I want when I slide slider then I get its minimum and maximum value in alert box using jQuery. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

```
<div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="price-min">Price:</label>
    <input type="range" name="price-min" id="price-min" value="500" min="0" max="2000">
    <label for="price-max">Price:</label>
    <input type="range" name="price-max" id="price-max" value="1000" min="0" max="2000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want this, as this creates a lot of alerts since it's range input.

```
$('[name="price-min"]').on('input', function(e){
  alert( $(this).val() );
})


$('[name="price-max"]').on('input', function(e){
  alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: Add an event handler so when it is changed, alert the value

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll need something like this (it isn't jQuery, just plain JS):

```
document.getElementById('range-min').addEventListener('change',e=>{
    alert(e.target.value)
})
document.getElementById('range-max').addEventListener('change',e=>{
    alert(e.target.value)
})
```